# Do not bind a file entry in Bind to wx. Button buttons in the loop

Tags: python, wxpython

Greetings to the respected community!

I have the following task: I need to create a panel with buttons whose names are taken from the file (all_classes). When clicking on each label, the buttons must be recorded in another file (chosen_classes). I managed to create buttons in the loop and arrange them on the panel, but the recording event to the button is not tied and I do not understand why.

```
all_classes = open('data/yolo2/yolo2.names', 'r').read().split()
chosen_classes = open('chosen_classes', 'w')

deltaxSize, deltaySize, c = 0, 0, 0
        for k, obj_class in enumerate(all_classes):
            self.buttons.append(wx.Button(self.panel, label=f'{obj_class}', pos=(50 + deltaxSize, 20 + deltaySize),
                                       size=(100, 20)))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: chosen_classes.write(f'{obj_class}\n'), self.buttons[k])
            deltaySize += 20
            c += 1
            if c == 30:
                deltaxSize += 100
                deltaySize, c = 0, 0
```

I tried instead of recording in the lambda just prints to check what was going on, but got a strange result: when you press any button, only the last label is displayed:

```
deltaxSize, deltaySize, c = 0, 0, 0
        self.buttons = []
        for k, obj_class in enumerate(all_classes):
            self.buttons.append(wx.Button(self.panel, label=f'{obj_class}', pos=(50 + deltaxSize, 20 + deltaySize),
                                       size=(100, 20)))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: print(f'{obj_class}\n'), self.buttons[k])
            deltaySize += 20
            c += 1
            if c == 30:
                deltaxSize += 100
                deltaySize, c = 0, 0
```

The same happens if you replace obj_class in the f-line with self.buttons [k]. GetLabelText () At the same time, if you turn to each button separately outside the loop, you can print the label, but the file still does not record. I am completely, admittedly, perplexed, if anyone can suggest anything, I would be infinitely grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have managed to over complicate your solution a bit.
The use of a `sizer` will make this easier and because the only `event` being fired is a button event and they all do the same thing, we only need to `bind` it once.
Pick the bones out of the following, it should help.

```
import wx

all_classes = ["abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"]
chosen_classes = open('chosen_classes.txt', 'w')

class ButtonPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.parent = parent

        for k, obj_class in enumerate(all_classes):
            self.add_button(obj_class)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.parent.Layout()

    def add_button(self, obj_class):
        self.sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label=f'{obj_class}'), 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)

    def OnButton(self,event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        label = obj.GetLabel()
        chosen_classes.write(label+" Pressed\n")
        print(label)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.button_panel = ButtonPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.button_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        panel = MyPanel(self)


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Sizer is really better idea.

Comment: @Menhel My pleasure, welcome to StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers